# How to save merged text file into a sub-directory in python?

Tags: python

I have two text files of different sub-directory in same folder. And I had merged into one new text file and saved it in a sub-directory.
I have a problem, my new text file is empty. It didn't saved information from given files. How to solve this?

```
files= ['/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/50961/Features.txt','/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/51562/Features.txt']

allfiles = fileinput.input(files)

for line in allfiles: 
    filepath = "/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/result.txt"
# result.txt is my new text file where I have merged files
     fout=open(filepath,"w+")
    print(filepath)
```

Comment: open file only once - before `for`-loop

Comment: and you have to write to file `fout.write(line)`

Comment: maybe you should use standard `read()` and `write()` to copy all text at once instead of geting line by line.

Comment: thank you, it's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import fileinput

files = [
    '/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/50961/Features.txt',
    '/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/51562/Features.txt'
]

filepath = "/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/result.txt"
fout = open(filepath, "w+")

allfiles = fileinput.input(files)
for line in allfiles: 
    fout.write(line)

fout.close()
```

The same with standard `read()`, `write()` without fileinput

```
files = [
    '/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/50961/Features.txt',
    '/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/51562/Features.txt'
]

filepath = "/Users/Desktop/Python/Data/result.txt"
fout = open(filepath, "w+")

for filename in files: 
    fout.write( open(filename).read() )

fout.close()
```